# How to write comparator to sort 2D array based on second column using lambda expression

Tags: lambda, java-8, comparator

I am working on a sorting 2D-Array problem in Java. I want to sort the array based on the second column in each row such as a[i][1]. I am trying to write a lambda expression to put it in Arrays.sort(a, comparator) to avoid writing a whole class.

Here is what I tried:

```
Arrays.sort(contests, (int[] num1, int[] num2) -> Integer number1 = num1[1];
   Integer number2 = num2[1];
    return number2.compareTo(number1);
);
```

I am not sure what is wrong because Java will not give me an exact error message when I run. I know that the first part of a lambda expression is the input, and the second part is comparing. Since .compareTo() only works for objects, that is why I create two Integers. Eclipse keeps telling me to insert; after Integer. Can anyone help me, please? Thank you

Comment: You have to wrap the body of your lambda in `{ }`. You're using the simplified lambda syntax for one-line-statements, but you actually have 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type definitions inside the lambda expression arise from the context, no further type-definitions are needed.
Your example is only working with the values from array `contests[1]`.
`Arrays.sort()` expects an 1-dimensional array.
If `contests` is defined as `Integer[][] array`, then this expression should work for You:

`Arrays.sort( contests[1], (num1, num2) -> ( num2.compareTo( num1 ) ) );`

*To sort both arrays corresponding — `Arrays.sort()` will not work:*

```
index1 = 0;  // defined as class variable
index2 = 0;  // defined as class variable
Arrays.stream( contests[1] ).map( (n) -> new Integer[] {
    contests[0][index1], contests[1][index1++]
} ).sorted( (arr1,arr2) -> Integer.compare( arr2[1], arr1[1] ) )
.forEach( (arr) -> {
  contests[0][index2] = arr[0];
  contests[1][index2++] = arr[1];
} );
```

One way is to pair the corresponding values (same index) of `contests[0]` with `contests[1]` and map these arrays to the `contest[1]` values.
After sorting write the values back in the `forEach` loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
Arrays.sort(contests,(int[] num1,int[] num2)->Integer.compare(num2[1],num1[1]));
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs for [`Arrays.sort(array, comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) one discovers that the input array must have a Class as a type, as the comparator compares Objects of type T.

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

So sorting 2D arrays in this manner will take more effort to get the structure to cooperate.

Alternatively, you can use Streams to allow you to accomplish your goal because of the autoboxing that will occur along the way. Here is a solution using Streams and a lambda as you requested:

```
int[][] contests = { { 1, 7 }, { 2, 5 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 } };
Arrays
  .stream(contests)
  .sorted((a1, a2) -> a1[1] - a2[1])
  .forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
```

A working sample can be found here: https://repl.it/@randycasburn/2D-array-sort

Comment: thank you so much !! Too bad I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer

Comment: Give it a second, I upvoted your question. By the way, you can always "Accept" my answer if you choose.

Answer (score 1):

this is for sorting 2d array (n*2) size

```
int a[][]=new int[n][2];
Arrays.sort(a,(x,y)->x[0]-y[0]);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Compare elements according to 1St coordinates if 1st coordinates are equal, sort based on 2nd coordinates.

```
Arrays.sort(contest,(a,b)->{
if(a[0]==b[0]){
return Integer.compare(a[1],b[1]);
}
return Integer.compare(a[0],b[0]);
});
```

This works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).